# How do I bound a generic type to 2 types that are almost completely separated in hierarchy

Tags: java, class, generics, types, hierarchy

How do I do this? Because you can only extend one class so it can only have one upper bound.

In my case I need the generic type to be bounded in String and int. If I use an Integer wrapper instead of int and rely on auto-boxing, I can make it  but the problem is other classes can be passed as a type parameter as well.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: this sounds like a bit of a mess, just use Object

Comment: You can't use primitives as generic types, you would need to use the wrapper class anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the non generic variants of collections (e.g  List), or 
more cleanly explicitly `List<Object>` to show code's intention.
Wrap that in a MyList class, and create add(), get() methods for each type you want to support:

```
add(Integer elem);
add(String elem);
```

But Object get() cannot be typed, such that it makes sense.

So finally you also can use Object with List, and omit the wrapper.

Comment: I would recommend using `List<Object>` over the rawtype `List`, so the code's intention is clear and you don't have to suppress any warnings (or is that what your last sentence is saying?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it. String also is a final class and all that stuff. As @NimChimpsky said, you are probably better using Object itself. Another solution is a wrapper for both classes, but you will still have a resulting object which you will probably need to cast around and rely on `instanceof`:

```
class StringInt {
  private String string;
  private Integer integer;

  public StringInt(String s) { this.string = s; }
  public StringInt(Integer i) { this.integer = i; }

  public Object getValue() { return string != null ? string : integer; }
}
```

Or with an ugly verification, which, obviously, will only apply at runtime...

```
class StringIntGen<T> {
  private T t;

  public StringIntGen(T t) { 
    if (!(t instanceof String) && !(t instanceof Integer)) 
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "StringIntGen can only be Integer or String");
    this.t = t; 
  }

  public T getValue() { return t; }

}
```